# Why is my mDNS server not resolving subdomains like 'foo.bar.local' using cURL or Chrome, but works fine on Safari for iOS?

Tags: node.js, mdns

I've set up an mDNS server which resolves a couple local domains to a target IP address, but I'm having some trouble with subdomains. As an example, my server is resolving `bar.local` and `foo.bar.local` to 192.168.1.1. However, using cURL or Chrome to try and resolve this domain only works for `bar.local`, not `foo.bar.local`. Still, using Safari on iOS resolves the subdomain correctly and works fine. Why does this happen?

An HTTP server is running on port 80.
I'm using Node.js with the module `mdns-server`, and here is my code:

```
const ip = '192.168.1.1'

const domains = ['bar.local', 'foo.bar.local']

const mdns = require('mdns-server')({
  reuseAddr: true,
  loopback: true,
  noInit: true
})

mdns.on('response', response => {
  console.log(`Response packet: ${JSON.stringify([].concat(response.answers || [], response.additionals || []), null, 2)}`)
})

mdns.on('query', query => {
  console.log(`Query packet: ${JSON.stringify([].concat(query.questions || []), null, 2)}`)

  query.questions.forEach(question => {
    domains.forEach(domain => {
      if (question.name === domain && question.type === 'A') {
        mdns.respond({
          answers: [
            {
              name: domain,
              type: 'A',
              ttl: 300,
              data: ip
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    })
  })
})

mdns.initServer()
```

I can run this command:

```
curl http://bar.local
```

It resolves (which displays in the server console):

```
Response packet: [
  {
    "name": "bar.local",
    "type": "A",
    "ttl": 300,
    "class": "IN",
    "flush": false,
    "data": "192.168.1.1"
  }
]
```

And uses the correct address.

However, using the subdomain:

```
curl http://foo.bar.local
```

Returns the following error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foo.bar.local
```

And does not show any querying on the server.